# Any knowledge on how to embed an image via PHPmail without using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, email, header

I would prefer to use what I already have and just add an image on if possible. Here is my code so far:

```
$to = $Email;
$subject = "$auth->first_name $auth->last_name left you a comment";
$message =  "$auth->first_name $auth->last_name left you a comment: <br /><br /> <a href='http://www.blah.org/Profile.php?id=" . $prof->id . "'>Click here to view</a>";
$from = "blah<noreply@blah.org>";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the HTML for the image in your `$message`.

```
$message = "Here is my image: <img src='http://www.mysite.com/1.jpg' />";
```

Be sure to use the absolute-url ("http://www.mysite...") as this will be loaded from recipient inbox's, and not from  your server.

Comment: I have tried that. Once adding to the end of the existing $message and once making an additional $message .=  

It won't even send the mail to my inbox at that point. Is there something I am missing?